# Adding CSS classes to an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <button onclick ="addClass(el,'Test') ">click</button>
</body>

<script>
    function addClass(element, myClass) {

         element.className = myClass; 
}
    var el = document.getElementById('foo');
</script>
```

I would like to add more more classes without the previous class being removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/DEuNF/)**</kbd>

Try this:

```
function addClass(element, myClass) {
    element.className += ' ' + myClass; 
}

var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
addClass(foo, 'a');
addClass(foo, 'b');
```

Comment: OK, +1 for that sweet kbd demo style :) I'm totally stealing it :)

Comment: @Phrogz It's yours... `:)`.

Answer (score 4):

CSS classes are space delimited in the attribute, so:

```
function addClass(element, myClass){
   element.className += ' '+myClass;
}
```

Or, for modern browsers, use [`classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.classList):

```
function addClass(element, myClass){
   element.classList.add(myClass);
}
```

…which you can even [polyfill for older browsers](https://gist.github.com/devongovett/1381839).

If you are not using `classList` and wanted to ensure that your `class` attribute has only one instance of a given class in the string, you can remove it first (totally unnecessary but for OCD):

```
var re = new RegExp( "(?:^|\\s)"+myClass+"(?:\\s|$)", 'g' );
el.className = el.className.replace(re, '');
```